# Iterate through a server URL of indexed directory and read files

Tags: python, http, directory, iterator

There is a directory on a http server whose url is http://somehost/maindir/recent/. And this "recent" directory contains say 50 zip sub directories.

I can read one zip file with

```
 zfile = "http://somehost/maindir/recent/1.zip"
 with RemoteZip(zfile) as zip:
        for zip_info in zip.infolist():
            data = zip.read(zip_info.filename)
```

But I am not getting any idea to iterate through "http://somehost/maindir/recent/" and read data from each zip. I tried glob, os.join, os.walk but in-vein .
I want something like this:

```
for zfile in baseurl: //unable to do this line.
    with RemoteZip(zfile) as zip:
        for zip_info in zip.infolist():
                data = zip.read(zip_info.filename)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot get the directory listing directly, As It's the HTTP server which is responsible for giving back the response ,in some cases you will get an HTML page displaying links to all the files inside a "directory" as in your case "http://somehost/maindir/recent/" will give you listing of all zip files inside recent directory but in a html format.

One solution could be to use Beautifulsoup to parse that html page and fetch all the links to zip files from that "recent" directory page.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'http://somehost/maindir/recent/'


def get_files(url):
   page = requests.get(url).text
  
   soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
   return [url + '/' + node.get('href') for node in soup.find_all('a') if 
           node.get('href').endswith('.zip')]
file_links = get_files(url)
for zfile in file_links:
    with RemoteZip(zfile) as zip:
        for zip_info in zip.infolist():
            data = zip.read(zip_info.filename)
```

Comment: I am such a noob to not to come up with this idea. Thank you! I got the list of zip files urls.